# TCP and UDP segmentation

Tags: networking

I know in networking, data stream is to be divided into different segments at layer 4. each segment is then encapsulated with port number and IP address. I found some confused questions that I would like to ask:

- Who is responsible in dividing the data stream into different segments. Is it the application or layer 4?
- I understood that UDP doesn't support segmentation. So how data stream is spitted into different segments for sending (As in VoIP application) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not really a programming question.

Comment: Might be more appropriate over at http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 0):

A TCP connection is a stream of bytes. The packetizing is done by the TCP/IP stack in the operating system.

UDP is *not* a stream - it is simply a bunch of datagrams, that are not guaranteed to arrive in any order (or at all). Any protocol implemented with UDP has to handle these details in their own application-specific way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So you say that Application is responsible in how big the UDP segment is. In where, for TCP the OS is responsible for that.??

Comment: No, application can't decide how big is the datagram size, it is MTU of outgoing interface, and that also is OS responsibility, If I am not wrong

Comment: If you send a 4000 byte UDP datagram out a link with an MTU of 1500, it is going to be fragmented.

Answer (score 0):

Application layer shouldn't be worried about segments(Transport layer packets in TCP communication). As it is being created by TCP layer. Theoretically Segment size can be as large as 65495. But it would be calculated based on the MTU of your outgoing interface, like ethernet card. So, application layer is not at all involved on segmentation of data stream. UDP is also at layer 4, but it doesn't support reliability as TCP. Otherwise datagram creation(Transport layer packets in UDP communication) is also exactly like segments in TCP.

Answer (score 0):

It is the responsibility of layer 3 to take care of the data fragmentation. The usual size of MTU is 576 bytes. So the network layer splits the transport layer segment into chunks of 576 bytes, adds its own header and sends it to the data link layer.

Even with UDP, fragmentation is possible. UDP has no knowledge of fragmentation and reassembly of the fragments since it is the network layer that performs these. Anything above 576 bytes is fragmented irrespective of the transport layer protocol.

In VoIP, blocks of data (20-30ms) are processed at a time and sent as a application layer message.